# Responsive - text on image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have problem with responsive design.  I try to display text over the box in image, but when I resize browser text is outside the box.

My picture: 
[image]

```css
.row6 {
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 130px;
  border: 0px salmon dotted;
  font: bold 1.7vw arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.row6 > div {
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url(images/background.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%
}

#dd7 {
  margin-left:44.7%;
  width:45px;
  text-align:center; 
  padding-top:0.7%
}
```

HTML code:

```html
<div class="row6">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div id="dd7">TEXT</div>
    </div>               
  </div>
</div>
```

What I should do to have text always in right place over image?

Comment: Put the background image on the div containing the text (`#dd7`).

Comment: But I have one big image with little place for text, that place (white box) must be in the correct part of image. This is reason why div with text is in div with image background.

Comment: Can you post a demo of your code on a site like jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pnzLn2no/

Comment: When you resize your browser text is outside the box

Comment: @Ruben Lech, First of all remove position relative from this class. - .row6 > .bgImage-.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stanze/pnzLn2no/2/)

```
.row6 {
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 130px;
  border: 0px salmon dotted;
  font: bold 1.7vw arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.row6 > .bgImage {  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/amwBH.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%
}

#dd7 {
  margin-left:44.7%;
  margin-top: 1.2%;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're using a fixed width (`45px`) for your text. Try using a percentage width instead:

```
#dd7{
...
width: 5%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pnzLn2no/1/